# Rendering a scene makes the background footage extremely bright

Tags: light

[image]
Not quite sure why this is happening. I even tried disabling lights.

Comment: Please post an image of your compositing nodes. Try to include more information about your scene on your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting computer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the *Compositing* screen layout, and then back to the *Default* screen layout. This should clear things up. I think maybe the nodes just need to load.